# Change a form label text value when setting a static int

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to change a form label's text value (`frmWebInput.ConnectedUserCount.Text`) when changing a static int value from another static void...

Basically: It's a simple web server, and I'm trying to keep track of the connected users when each page is served. It seems to be working, but the form label is not getting changed though?

```
/**
 * @type int Total connected users.
 */
 private static int _connectedUsers = 0;
 public static int connectedUsers {
     get { return _connectedUsers; }
     set
     {
         _connectedUsers = value;
         frmWebInput MyForm = new frmWebInput();
         MyForm.ConnectedUserCount.Text = String.Format("Connected Users: {0}", value);
     }
 }

public static void clientListener()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpListenerContext request = listener.GetContext();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(processRequest, request);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {  }
        }
    }

public static void processRequest(object listenerContext)
{
        try
        {
           connectedUsers = connectedUsers + 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new form every time the static is set.  Do you have a static reference to the form somewhere?

Comment: Is this application multi-threaded? (I assume so, since a web server may receive requests any time.) You need to add locking to properly guard the static value(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a WinForms application running on the web server?  Or is this a WebForm?

In any event, you never show the form:

```
frmWebInput MyForm = new frmWebInput();
MyForm.ConnectedUserCount.Text = String.Format("Connected Users: {0}", value);
```

Every time the value is set, you create a new instance of `frmWebInput` and set the text on that instance.  But you never show it.  If one is already shown elsewhere in the application, you never set its text.

You need a reference to the instance of the form being shown.  Something like:

```
private static frmWebInput MyForm { get; set; }

private static int _connectedUsers = 0;
public static int connectedUsers {
    get { return _connectedUsers; }
    set
    {
        _connectedUsers = value;
        MyForm.ConnectedUserCount.Text = String.Format("Connected Users: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

And, of course, that reference would have to be set with the instance of the form.  Since it's `static` it would have to be within the static initializer.  Either that or instead of an auto-implemented property it can just be a `get` which dynamically fetches the instance of the form.  It's difficult to advise on the best approach since I don't know how this code interacts with the form instance.

Comment: Don't forget about synchronizing the static.

Comment: @xxbbcc: Indeed, thread safety may well become an issue here.  The bigger picture of this application's architecture likely has some flaws.

Comment: Lol, yes, it looks fishy. :) Maybe it's just an experiment.

Comment: lol sorry, it's just a pet project as I'm basically teaching myself C# in the process!!

Comment: @c0nfus3d1: In that case the main issue you're facing is that two instances of the same type are not actually the same thing.  For example, imagine in real life if you buy two identical cars.  They're the same in every way, but they're not the same car.  In this case, you need your code to have a reference to the existing instance rather than create a new instance.

Comment: It may be all kinds of wrong, but I just committed the current source to https://github.com/c0nfused/Web-Remote-Input

It was kind of working, but then I wanted to keep track of the number of people, and now it's all breaking again :'(

https://github.com/c0nfused/Web-Remote-Input/blob/master/WebInput/WebInput.cs being this current file

Comment: So yeah, it's just a personal project to see what I can do. I know things may be wrong, but I'm learning!!! Thanks for the info and advice!! :)